# ggplot and scale_x_continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2

here a sample of data :

```
library(ggplot2)
lbreaks=c(-800,-600,-400,-300,-200,-100,-75,-50,-25,0,25,50)
ddf=data.frame(x=lbreaks,
y=seq(1,length(lbreaks),1))
```

and the scatter plot corresponding
[image]

I would use a custom scale (log or something similar for positive and negative values) for x-axis values to generate the same scatterplot with the equally spaced interval of x values. I tried to use several function in `scale_x_continuous(trans =`  without sucess.
How could I do this ?
Many thanks for your help,

Comment: It seems that you're trying to manipulate the x-axis - making equal distances on the axis represent different differences in x. Just a warning that this can make the graph difficult to interpret, or even deceiving. I would avoid doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the x axis breaks to be evenly spaced, the simplest thing to do is:

```r
ggplot(ddf, aes(factor(x), y)) + 
  geom_point(colour = 'red') +
  labs(x = 'x')
```

[image]

Perhaps less flippantly, your specific transformation can only really be achieved accurately by a piecewise transformation function:

```r
my_trans <- scales::trans_new('custom',
                      transform = function(x) {
                        dplyr::case_when(
                          x < -400 ~ (x + 800) / 200 + 1,
                          x < -100 ~ (x + 400) / 100 + 3,
                          TRUE ~ (x + 100) / 25 + 6)
                      },
                      inverse = function(x) {
                        dplyr::case_when(
                          x < 3 ~ (x - 1) * 200 - 800,
                          x < 6 ~ (x - 3) * 100 - 400,
                          TRUE ~ (x - 6) * 25 - 100)
                      })


ggplot(ddf, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(colour = 'red') +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = my_trans, breaks = lbreaks)
```

[image]

This allows arbitrary data to be passed:

```r
ddf=data.frame( x=rnorm(100,mean=-500,sd=200), y=rnorm(100,mean=0.5,sd=0.2) )

ggplot(ddf, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(colour = 'red') +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = my_trans, breaks = lbreaks)
```

[image]

However, such arbitrary x axis manipulations are not ideal, as they can be misleading.

Comment: Many thanks . If we use now a more consequent sample data as follow ddf=data.frame(
x=rnorm(100,mean=-500,sd=200),
y=rnorm(100,mean=0.5,sd=0.2)
)`

Comment: @Ochees see my update, which shows the 'real' transform.